# What is meant by (a,b) = (1,2)?

Tags: c#

This code:

```
(int a,int b) = (1,0)
(a, m) = (m, a % m);
(x, y) = (y, x - q * y);
```

How is it different to this:

```
int a=1;
int b=0;
a = m;
m = a%m;
x = y;
y = x-q*y;
```

Why is it not the same?
How do you write it in the normal way without parentheses?

Comment: _[Check out tuples in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)_

Comment: I understood. The sequence of actions is important here. So the codes are not equivalent.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, there is nothing non-normal in the first case. As @MickyD referenced, you should read about [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples). This version is more concise, so I actually prefer it.

More importantly, these code snippets are not equal. Compare

```
(a, m) = (m, a % m);
```

vs

```
a = m;
m = a%m;
```

In the second case `a` is evaluated first, meaning that `m` will become `0` in the end:

```
a = m; // now a equals m
m = a%m; // m := a % m = m % m = 0
```

In the first case all parts of tuples are computed simultaneously (like in e.g. Python). In other words, it's equivalent (in terms of result) to the following code:

```
int temp = a;
a = m;
m = temp % m;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I understand.